# Xamarin, C#, Google Maps fragment with SupportMapFragment doesn't work with Min 10 Target 11

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin, supportmapfragment

In post [Xamarin, C#, Google Maps fragment not responding to any commands. (i.e MoveCamera)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558863/xamarin-c-google-maps-fragment-not-responding-to-any-commands-i-e-movecamer), @Robbit, posts a github package which works just fine with the included Target 8.1 and current-at-that-time Nugut packages.

However, as I update the project with latest packages and target 11 and min 10, and rebuild, the code now gets an error:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);
mapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);
```

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0030  Cannot convert type 'Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment' to 'Android.Gms.Maps.SupportMapFragment'  App46   GoogleMapXamarinTest-master\App46\MainActivity.cs   29  Active*

[Visual Studio showing the can't convert fragement pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30LKL.png)

I do not understand why -- can someone please explain ?

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164459/cannot-convert-type-android-support-v4-app-fragment-to-android-gms-maps-mapfr

Comment: Does not seem to work as in my case where now I have min build version as 10 and target as 11, while using latest nugut packages.  As I mention, using the earlier build values it does.  Something has changed.   Or, am I missing a subtle point ?

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT, as mentioned in the thread you reference, it is said to use SupportMapFragment, - that is what my code snippet at top is doing.   As an experiment, my line of code using SupportMapFragment works using Min 8.0 and Target 8.1.  But as I moved the code to build with Min 10 and Target 11, I start getting the errors.   What does one do now ?

Comment: did you update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX);  like this instruction shows  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: No, unaware of that -- I will read and try it and respond back -- thanks.

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT, so I can see the following AndroidX FragmentManager now per:   var x = AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.mymapfragmentID); but this gives me:   
Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(int)' GPSSatellite5 C:\code\Xamarin\GPSSatellite6\GPSSatellite5\MapActivity.cs Why would this happen ?

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT, ah - I see since in AdroidX, the FragmentManager is an abstract class, so I have inherited to a new class and call the method... will continue on shortly with my findings.

Comment: OK, here is the answer and it does include using the AndroidX:

    myFragmentManager fragmentManager = new myFragmentManager();
    var mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)fragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.mymapfragmentID);

And expand the class:

    public class myFragmentManager : AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager
    {
    }